# Why go package code has no body?

Tags: go, package

I wondered coding style of go package when studying exporting packaging.

and found that the code of package in source(ex:"math", "fmt") has

function begins with a capital letter but no body.

I just follow this code but doesn't work.

Anyone who explain why??

```
func Abs(x float64) float64

func abs(x float64) float64 {
    switch {
    case x < 0:
        return -x
    case x == 0:
        return 0 // return correctly abs(-0)
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

those functions are implemented in Assembler (https://golang.org/doc/asm) 
there are platform specific implementations for them: take a look at e.g.:

`$GOROOT/src/math/abs_amd64.s`

for

`func Abs(x float64) float64`